# Comparing beginner homebrew kits?

Tags: kits

Any thoughts on the [Midwest Supplies Beer, Simply Beer](https://www.midwestsupplies.com/simply-beer-brewing-starter-kit) kit vs the [Basic Brewer's Best 1000](http://www.brewersbestkits.com/equipment.html) kit?  They seem pretty comparable, but I'm curious if I'm overlooking something because I'm a newb.

P.S. I have a 5 gal kettle

Comment: Can we close this question?  The inquirer hasn't logged in again since they joined, and more answers are piling on but not adding value.

Answer (score 1):

The Basic Brewers Best 1000 kit wins in my opinion because it comes with a thermometer and hydrometer, which the other kit does not.  These are important tools for any homebrewers.  Alternatively, of course, you can just purchase these separately.  But the Midwest kit is really incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I just bought myself this one:

https://www.brewtek.ca/micro-brew/micro-brew-blond-23-liter-631021

Not sure if it's good. Last time I tried the "Brooklyn" one :

https://www.amazon.ca/Brooklyn-Brew-Shop-Making-Bruxelles/dp/B00CFJLUNK/ref=sr_1_6?

But my batch was undrinkable. Wish me luck this time. :/

Comment: This answer is not particularly relevant to the topic at hand.  We are discussing two equipment kits brought up by Tom.  Plus this is an old thread anyway.  I'm not sure if Tom is even still watching this thread.  Likely not.  But I do wish you better luck on your next batch.  Post new Questions if you have any.  But not under this thread please.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with @dmtaylor, get the Basic Brewers Best 1000 kit out of those 2 as it had hydrometer and thermometer. With out these 2 basic tools making beer is rather more challenging.

Things I would add on to of one of these kits (in addition to your beer ingredients) are:

1. Campden Tabletes to knock the chorine ions out of your brewing water
2. A couple of extra yeast packs, many kits come with very small packs of yeast ~6g to save costs, I would typically pitch into 25l/5g about 22g/1oz of yeast.
3. almost forgot get some extra sanitising chemicals, things can never be too clean.

And, as always good luck and have fun!

Answer (score -1):

biggest difference is simply beer comes with a pale ale. 
both have pretty much the same stuff in them.

Comment: It doesn't come with ingredients like for a pale ale... at least not anymore.